# Getting error while executing redis migrate command

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I am trying to execute the below command

```
migrate x.x.x.x 6379 key destinationserver COPY
```

and I am getting the error

```
(error) ERR value is not an integer or out of range
```

Also these redis servers have authetication.. I am not sure how to provide it with this command

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `help migrate` in redis-cli, it gives you better information about how to use the `MIGRATE` command than the docs (which tell you how it works). Here's the output I get:

```
MIGRATE host port key| destination-db timeout [COPY] [REPLACE] [KEYS key]
  summary: Atomically transfer a key from a Redis instance to another one.
  since: 2.6.0
  group: generic
```

The `destination-db` here is referring to the database id within redis. By default, a redis system has 16 databases, numbers 0-15, so where you have `destinationserver` in your example, it should be the database id to put the data in. That's why you're getting the error, it needs to be an INT id of the database.

For AUTH, as long as your Redis version is 4.0.7 or higher, `MIGRATE` supports an AUTH keyword in the following form:

```
MIGRATE 127.0.0.2 6379 key 0 5000 AUTH my_password COPY
```

If you have Redis version 6.0.0 or higher, you can supply a username as well, though there's no information about this in the docs or in the output I have, but I'm not yet running version 6.

Comment: Thanks Adam.. This answer is helpful. So I cant use this query to migrate the data from one server to another.

Comment: You can, you just need to specify the database id to use. If it’s a new redis server, 0 is a good default.

Comment: but where is the option to provide the 2nd instance information

Comment: There isn't one because you can only run the migrate command from the "source" system. So you have to do a `redis-cli -h redis.example.com` (or run it from the source redis host itself). The command tells the local redis instance (whichever you're logged into) to migrate its data to the target you specify in the parameters to migrate.